# MongoDB - Update data type for the nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I have this collection: (see the full collection here https://mongoplayground.net/p/_gH4Xq1Sk4g)

```
{
  "_id": "P-00",
  "nombre": "Woody",
  "costo": [
    {
      "tipo": "Cap",
      "detalle": "RAC",
      "monto_un": "7900 ",
      "unidades": "1",
      "total": "7900 "
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried a lot of ways to transform `monto_un`, `unidades` and `total` into int, but I always get an error.
Neither of these works.

```
db.proyectos.updateMany({}, {'$set': {"costo.monto_un": {'$toInt': 'costo.$.monto_un'}}})
```

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      costo: {
        monto_un: {
          $toInt: {
            costo: "$monto_un"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

MongoDB 5.0.9
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set` - Update `costo` array.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate each element in the `costo` array and return a new array.

   1.2. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current document with the document from *1.3*.

   1.3. A document with the `monto_un` field. You need to trim space for the `monto_un` field in the current iterate document via `$trim` and next convert it to an integer via `$toInt`.

In case you are also required to convert the `unidades` and `total` as `int`, add those fields with the same operator/function logic as `monto_un` in *1.3*. Those fields in the document (*1.3*) will override the existing value due to `$mergeObjects` behavior.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      costo: {
        $map: {
          input: "$costo",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                monto_un: {
                  $toInt: {
                    $trim: {
                      input: "$$this.monto_un"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jpSYsPl_299)